# Convert HashBytes to VarChar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the MD5 Hash of a string value in SQL Server 2005. I do this with the following command:

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', 'HelloWorld')
```

However, this returns a VarBinary instead of a VarChar value. If I attempt to convert `0x68E109F0F40CA72A15E05CC22786F8E6` into a VarChar I get `há ðô§*à\Â'†øæ` instead of `68E109F0F40CA72A15E05CC22786F8E6`.

Is there any SQL-based solution?

**[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120/#2382)**

Answer (score 163, accepted):

I have found the solution else where:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', 'HelloWorld')), 3, 32)
```

Comment: fn_varbintohexstr is not documented function. Use CONVERT(Char,@value,2)

Comment: I just got bit by varbinary as needing a way for update into the warehouse.  This worked like a charm!  thanks...

Comment: This method is very slow, uses an undocumented function and doesn't work in Azure. Not cool. Use Convert instead!

Comment: CONVERT() doesn't work in SQL 2005. If you're using SQL 2008 or above, then use CONVERT() all you want. Sadly I'm not aware of a single command which will work for all SQL versions, so either do some crazy version checking in your script, or just make a note somewhere that you need to fix the function if you upgrade SQL versions.

Comment: CONVERT(Char,@value,2) only outputs 32 bytes - if you do this to a sha1 hash you will truncate it, you need convert(char(48),@value,2) to keep the appropriate output.

Comment: Ahh, good old Microsoft SQL Server... such a clean/obvious/succinct function. ;)  .. Compare that to the php equivalent: md5()

Comment: @AndrewHill it's actually 40 characters.  sha1 is 160bit long and the characters use 4bit each, so 160/4 gives you 40 characters.

Comment: The problem with `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr` is that you can not use it with SCHEMABINDING

Comment: I think the question should be modified to have SQL server 2005 in both title and tag as this is a version specific solution. For newer SQL servers the answer by Rapscallion/Jason Plank is more effective as many have noted.

Answer (score 118):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', 'Hello World'),2)
```

Comment: this works in SQL Azure. for SHA1 : SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), HashBytes('SHA1', 'Hello World'), 2)

Comment: No need to use nvarchar unnecessarily.

Comment: The question states SQL Server 2005 and if you do either of the suggestions above in it (and probably any other version as well) they do not do what is asked for.  You get whatever character the bytes are equivalent to, not the bytes as a hex string which is what is asked for.  GateKiller and Xarqron give answers that work.

Comment: Where can I read about these convert styles? **2** in this case which is passed as the parameter.
And how to make an equivalent of that in C# code? What encoding should I choose?

Answer (score 32):

Use `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', @input), 1, 0)` instead of `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr` and then `substringing` the result.

In fact `fn_varbintohexstr` calls `fn_varbintohexsubstring` internally. The first argument of `fn_varbintohexsubstring` tells it to add `0xF` as the prefix or not. `fn_varbintohexstr` calls `fn_varbintohexsubstring` with `1` as the first argument internaly.

Because you don't need `0xF`, call `fn_varbintohexsubstring` directly.

Answer (score 30):

Contrary to what [David Knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161332/david-knight) says, these two alternatives return the same response in MS SQL 2008:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', 'Hello World'),2)
SELECT UPPER(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('MD5', 'Hello World'), 1, 0))
```

So it looks like the first one is a better choice, starting from version 2008.

Comment: Do not type this by mistake which gives a subtly different answer!... convert(varchar, HashBytes('MD5', 'Hello World')), 2)

Comment: correct, I had missed the ",2 " from the convert which is the important part

Answer (score 17):

```
convert(varchar(34), HASHBYTES('MD5','Hello World'),1)
```

(1 for converting hexadecimal to string)

convert this to lower and remove 0x from the start of the string by substring:

```
substring(lower(convert(varchar(34), HASHBYTES('MD5','Hello World'),1)),3,32)
```

exactly the same as what we get in C# after converting bytes to string

Answer (score 1):

With personal experience of using the following code within a Stored Procedure which Hashed a SP Variable I can confirm, although undocumented, this combination works 100% as per my example:

```
@var=SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('SHA2_512', @SPvar)), 3, 128)
```

Comment: Duplicate of the accepted answer + SHA2_512 hashing algorithm produces 256 characters so you loose the second part of the hash with the SUBSTRING

Answer (score -3):

Changing the datatype to varbinary seems to work the best for me.