# Almost the same Hash value

Tags: c#, sql, hash

**Goal:**
Retrieve the same hash value from SQL and C# code.

**Problem:**
The value of the hash is almost the same. I'm using the same hash and sha.

**Input:**
"Hello World!'"

**C# code:**
https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YbFXY

**SQL code:**

```
DECLARE @HashThis varchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(varchar(32),'Hello World!');  
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis);
```

**Output:**
Result of C# code:

> "7f83b1657ff1fc53b92dc18148a1d65dfc2d4b1fa3d677284addd200126d9069"

Result of SQL code:

> "0x7F83B1657FF1FC53B92DC18148A1D65DFC2D4B1FA3D677284ADDD200126D9069"

Is there a good or recommended approach to remove the data "0x"?

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186965/what-do-numbers-using-0x-notation-mean#:~:text=In%20C%20and%20languages%20based,1024%2C%20or%20one%20binary%20K.) help? Otherwise you could just detect the `0x` in the hash with `StartsWith` and remove the first two characters.

Comment: you can say the hash code IS the same, only the representation differs. Removing the 0x and downcasing makes it suitable for comparison.

Comment: The hashes are identical, formatted differently. A *hash* isn't a string anyway, it's a binary value. If you want to store and compare the actual hash values, don't format them as strings

Comment: Do you have to convert the hashes to strings? The real hash values are the byte[] `data` variable in your C# code and the binary value returned by `HASHBYTES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @HashThis varchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(varchar(32),'Hello World!');  
SELECT CONVERT(char(64), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis), 2)
```

But if you send down a binary to the database you should be able to compare that to the result of HASHBYTES without any convert. The same if you bring it up to you C# app as byte[].

Answer (score 2):

Change
`SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis);` to

`SELECT SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('SHA2_256', @HashThis)), 3, 64)`

Taken from [Convert HashBytes to VarChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120/convert-hashbytes-to-varchar)

As @Magnus pointed out in the comments, substring length should be 64.

Comment: It should be 64 and not 32

Comment: The 32 in the end is the length parameter to the substring function

Comment: Which makes the string to short